# SQL: Unix Timestamp entrys with Zero

Tags: php, mysql

i misunderstand why my query gives me entrys with an Timestamp of `0`. Can anyone say me what im doing wrong?

**Query:**

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `changes`
WHERE
        `time_from`>=1393628400
    AND
        `time_to`<=1394838000
    AND
        `area`='USERNAME'
ORDER BY
    `time_from` DESC,
    `time_to` DESC
```

**PHP**

```
$time_from  = (isset($_POST['time_from']) ? strtotime($_POST['time_from']) : null);
$time_to    = (isset($_POST['time_to']) ? strtotime($_POST['time_to']) : null);

if(empty($time_from) && empty($time_to)) {
    /* Do Nothing */
} else {
    if(!empty($time_from) && $time_from > 0 && !empty($time_to) && $time_to > 0) {
        $query  = sprintf(' `time_from`>=%d AND `time_to`<=%d', $time_from, $time_to);
    } else if(!empty($time_from) && $time_from > 0) {
        $query  = sprintf(' `time_from`>=%d', $time_from);
    } else if(!empty($time_to) && $time_to > 0) {
        $query  = sprintf(' `time_to`<=%d', $time_to);
    }

    $results        = $wpdb->get_row(sprintf('SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `%sarea_changes` WHERE%s AND `area`=\'%s\'', $wpdb->prefix, $query, $user->user_login));
    $count          = $results->count;

    if($count < 10) {
        $position       = 0;
        $has_more_pages = false;
    }

    $pages          = ceil($count / $max_rows);
    $query          = sprintf('SELECT * FROM `%sarea_changes` WHERE%s AND `area`=\'%s\' ORDER BY `time_from` DESC, `time_to` DESC', $wpdb->prefix, $query, $user->user_login, $position, $max_rows);
    print $query;
    $entrys         = $wpdb->get_results($query); // LIMIT %d, %d
}
```

**POST Data:**

`time_from` is `01.03.2014` and `time_to` is `15.03.2014`

But i get following entrys (see the `time_to`), why is that `0` that dont match my Query?

**Screenshot:**
*(Hidden data for privacy policy)*
[image]

Comment: Isn't because your query is `time_to<=1394838000` and 0 is an acceptable value? Just change the clause to : `AND time_to BETWEEN time_from AND  1394838000`

Comment: i check both: `time_from>=1393628400 AND time_to<=1394838000`. confusing, 0 is NOT in the range!

Comment: That's not a range, that is saying X>=A AND Z<=B. Each variable is completely independent of the other. Try the the clause I gave you which enforces time_to has to be after time_from

Comment: ah its an logical problem, visualize that. Yes its not an range. Currently added to check if it's Zero (`AND time_from!=0 AND time_to!=0`)